# how to detect shared letter between two words in javaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have this function
this function has to detect numeric and nonnumeric numbers like **'one'**  or **'1'**;
but the trickiest part is when when you have something like '**twone**' in there you have both **'one'** and **'two'**, and **o** is common for solving this problem.

I decided **not to increase** the pointer **'i'** to **keep** the **last word** and check again that is there any numbers starts with 'o',

but in this case **'twothree'**; it fails.

because you keep **'o'** and but the next letter is **'t'** and there is no numbers starts with **'ot'**,
So in this case I need to **increase** pointer **'i'** because I have 'three'

this is my code

```
function detectNumbers(input) {
    const wordToNumbers = new Map([
        ['zero', '0'],
        ['one', '1'],
        ['two', '2'],
        ['three', '3'],
        ['four', '4'],
        ['five', '5'],
        ['six', '6'],
        ['seven', '7'],
        ['eight', '8'],
        ['nine', '9']
    ]);

    let outStr = '';
    let myStr = '';
   
    let i = 0;
while (i < input.length) {
    if (!isNaN(Number(input[i]))) {
        myStr = ''; // Reset myStr if the character is a number
        outStr += input[i];
        i++;
    } else {
        myStr += input[i];
    
        let keyFound = false; 
        for (const key of wordToNumbers.keys()) {
            if (key.startsWith(myStr)) {
                keyFound = true; // Set flag to true if a key is found
                i++;
                if (wordToNumbers.has(myStr)) {
                    outStr += wordToNumbers.get(myStr);
                    myStr = '';
                    i--;
                    break; // Exit the loop after finding a word and getting a number
                }else break;
            }
        }

        if (!keyFound) {
            myStr = ''; // Reset myStr if no key is found
            i++;
        }
    }
}
    
    const result = outStr.length > 0 ? outStr[0] + outStr[outStr.length - 1] : outStr[0] + outStr[0];
    
    return parseFloat(result);
    
}
detectNumbers('eightwothree')
```

Comment: So what actual result do you want, when your input is `twone`? Is that supposed to detect both `two` and `one`? Or is it supposed to detect the `two` only, because the numbers are not allowed to "overlap"?

Comment: in this case "twone" should detect "21" and for "twothree" should be "23";                           "eightwothree" --->' 823'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a tree of characters for numbers and walk through it:

```js
const wordToNumbers = new Map([['zero', '0'], ['one', '1'], ['two', '2'], ['three', '3'], ['four', '4'], ['five', '5'], ['six', '6'], ['seven', '7'], ['eight', '8'], ['nine', '9']]);

let tree = {};

// build a tree of characters being nodes and digits being leaves
// then we could navigate character by character in the tree and find the corresponding digit if the path isn't broken while walking
for (const [k,v] of wordToNumbers.entries()) {
    let node = tree;
    for (const c of k.slice(0, -1)) {
        node = (node[c] ??= {});
    }
    node[k.at(-1)] = parseInt(v);
}

function detectNumbers(input) {
  let out = '';
  // we use 2 arrays with current nodes and next iteration nodes 
  // we mutate arrays and don't resize/recreate them for speed
  // the both arrays should contain the root node so we could start from the root with each character in the input string
  let curr = [tree], currLen = 1, next = [tree], nextLen = 1;
  
  // walk through characters in the provided string
  for (const c of input) {
      // if the character is a digit, just add it to the result and continue with the next character
      if(c >= 0 && c <=9){
        out += c;
        currLen = 1;
        nextLen = 1;
        continue;
      }
      // analyze the current nodes (initially just the root one)
      // and if the current character is found in them, collect the next iteration nodes
      for (let i = 0; i < currLen; i++) {
          const node = curr[i];
          if (c in node) { // we found the current input string's character in a node
              // if it's a number - add it to the result (we found our digit (leaf))
              if (typeof node[c] === 'number') {
                  out += node[c];
                  continue;
              }
              // add the found node for the next iteration
              next[nextLen++] = node[c];
          }
      }
      // swap current and next nodes to avoid creating new arrays
      [curr, currLen, next, nextLen] = [next, nextLen, curr, 1];
  }
  return out;
}
console.log(detectNumbers('eightwothree'));
console.log(detectNumbers('twone'));
console.log(detectNumbers('threeight4'));
console.log(detectNumbers('twoneightwo5nineight'));

// that's how our tree looks
console.log('tree:', tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{ top: 0; max-height: 100% !important }
```

Comment: It worked, could you explain your approach to me ?

Comment: @NegarNasiri optimized and added comments

Answer (score 1):

- Simply check for every substring in the string. If the current character is a digit, add it to the result and move ahead.
- While checking for every substring, check if it exists in the map, if it does, add the digit from the word in the map and break right away paving chance for the next possible words which could be representing the digits.
- Note that while checking for the substring, if the current character happens to be a digit, break right away, since a digit can't come inside a word.

```js
function detectNumbers(input) {
  const wordToNumbers = new Map([
    ['zero', '0'],
    ['one', '1'],
    ['two', '2'],
    ['three', '3'],
    ['four', '4'],
    ['five', '5'],
    ['six', '6'],
    ['seven', '7'],
    ['eight', '8'],
    ['nine', '9']
  ]);
  out = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    if (input.charAt(i) >= '0' && input.charAt(i) <= '9') {
      out += input.charAt(i);
      continue;
    }
    temp = '';
    for (let j = i; j < input.length; ++j) {
      if (input.charAt(j) >= '0' && input.charAt(j) <= '9') break;
      temp += input.charAt(j);
      if (wordToNumbers.has(temp)) {
        out += wordToNumbers.get(temp);
        break;
      }else if(j - i + 1 > 5){// since max length of any digit word is 5
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return out;
}

console.log(detectNumbers('eightwothree'));
console.log(detectNumbers('twone'));
console.log(detectNumbers('threeight4'));
console.log(detectNumbers('twoneightwo5nineight'));
console.log(detectNumbers('1ght8eightwo5nineight'));
```

**Time complexity:** `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the string.

**Space Complexity:** `O(1)` since the space doesn't grow with the input size.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is checking all words inside the string and then sorting them by index:

```js
function detectNumbers(input) {
    let results = []
    const wordToNumbers = new Map([
        ['zero', '0'],
        ['one', '1'],
        ['two', '2'],
        ['three', '3'],
        ['four', '4'],
        ['five', '5'],
        ['six', '6'],
        ['seven', '7'],
        ['eight', '8'],
        ['nine', '9']
    ]);
    const words = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']

    words.forEach(word => {
      // Check if the word is found
      if (input.includes(word)) {
        // Count how many times the word is found
        let count = input.split(word).length - 1;
        let lastIndex = 0
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          // Get the index
          let index = input.indexOf(word, lastIndex)
          lastIndex = index + 1
          results.push({index, word}) 
        }

      }
    })
    
    // Sort by index
    results.sort((a,b) => a.index - b.index)
    
    // Map to numbers
    let mapped = results.map(r => wordToNumbers.get(r.word))
    
    // Join the result
    return mapped.join('')
    
}
console.log(detectNumbers('twoneightwonineight'))
console.log(detectNumbers('twone'))
```

Comment: and for detecting numeric numbers, what should I do?  I mean this part                                                       if (!isNaN(Number(input[i]))) {
        myStr = ''; // Reset myStr if the character is a number
        outStr += input[i];
        i++;
    }

Comment: Because I need to detect both numeric and nonnumeric like :                                     input: ""1ght8eightwothree"" ---> output :"" 18823""

Comment: @NegarNasiri doesn't work `twoneightwonineight` either

Comment: Made an edit so double numbers do work. However as there is another answer already accepted, I am not going to do the reverse as well.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the rules imply that you need to check for words starting at every digit, which makes it relatively simple just to walk through the object with iteration or recursion.  Here's a recursive version:

```js
const digitNames =  ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
const wordToNumbers = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(digitNames).map(e => e.reverse()))

const detectNumbers = (s, r = '', w = digitNames.find(p => s.startsWith(p))) => 
  s.length == 0 
    ? r
    : detectNumbers(s.slice(1), r + (s[0].match(/\d/) ? s[0] : w ? wordToNumbers[w] : ''))

console.log(detectNumbers('eightwothree'));
console.log(detectNumbers('twone'));
console.log(detectNumbers('threeight4'));
console.log(detectNumbers('twoneightwo5nineight'));
console.log(detectNumbers('1ght8eightwo5nineight'));
console.log(detectNumbers('twoneightwonineight '));
```

If our input string is empty, we return the result we've been accumulating.  Otherwise we recur, passing everything but the first character of the string, and our result appended with either the first character, if it's a digit, the numeric value of the first number-word found starting with the first character, or an empty string, if no word is found.

Since we want both the word numbers and a map of their values (in this case an `Object`, but a `Map` would work equally well), we derive the latter from the former, and use both versions in the function.

Note that this technique, and even the basic requirements, depend on the fact that no digit word is a prefix of another.  If we wanted to include words up to twenty, we'd have to contend with the fact that "fourteen" starts with "four", and would need more sophisticated rules.

Answer (score -2):

```
function detectNumbers(input) {
    const wordToNumbers = [
        ['zero', '0o'],
        ['one', 'o1e'],
        ['two', 't2o'],
        ['three', 't3e'],
        ['four', '4'],
        ['five', '5e'],
        ['six', '6'],
        ['seven', '7n'],
        ['eight', 'e8t'],
        ['nine', 'n9e']
    ];
    for(let i=0;i<10;++i)
        input = input.replaceAll(wordToNumbers[i][0],wordToNumbers[i][1]);
    input = input.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
    return parseFloat(input);
}
detectNumbers('8oneightwone');
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves this issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).